# Can I enable Chrome DevTools Network to log requests all the time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I open the DevTools and switch to the Network Tab, I see a message 'No requests captured'. I then need to reload the page to see the activity.

Is there a way to always have this tab running so I can hit `F12` any time and immediately begin inspecting the network requests?

Comment: Feature request has been created: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. A site may have many requests and we will waste too much memory for this feature without a guarantee that this information is necessary.

Comment: Does chrome still not let you do this? I mean, it logs all responses, why not give you (as dev) the **option** to log all requests. If so, I would be happy about a hint **where to look** because I can't find any such thing in the network tab. If not, please consider adding this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's Dev Tools do not do that. But there are tools that can help achieve that outcome:

Chrome plugins:

- [Web Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef)
- [HTTP Trace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-trace/idladlllljmbcnfninpljlkaoklggknp)

Apps (I'm listing those for Mac):

- [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/)
- [Postman with its Interceptor plugin](https://www.postman.com/) (does not save responses)